What is the support detection probability after sparse recovery using OMP and Random sampling

I am working on Compressive spectrum sensing CSS. I performed random sampling, OMP recovery. The detection is done by finding nonzero amplitudes in the recovered spectrum to decide the belonging of the index (frequency) to the support. The support detection probability Pd depends on the signal length N, measurements number M, sparsity level K, and the signal to noise ratio SNR.
Can you help me find an approximation of this formula Pd=f(SNR,M,N,K)?

I am also doing cooperation in an L-network through the AND Rule. The cooperative detection probability Qd is shown to be supperior than Pd^L (AND-Rule with independent channels).
2.1 What is the Qd appoximation according to Pd or (SNR,M,N,K,L)?
2.2 What is the reason of the supperiority of Qd over Pd^L?


